# Magento2 change time for datepicker

Tags: magento2, date

Currently, time for Holiday time picker is

[from] => 2021-03-24 00:00:00
[to] => 2021-03-24 00:00:00

Need to change to

[from] => 2021-03-24 00:00:00
[to] => 2021-03-24 23:59:59

The following is the code I have used

```
 $fieldset->addField('to', 'date', [
            'name'        => 'to',
            'label'       => __('To Date'),
            'title'       => __('To Date'),
            'date_format' => 'M/d/yyyy',
            'timezone'    => false,
            'value'       => $this->_dateTime->date('m/d/Y')
        ]);
```

Comment: if end time is fixed then you can append 23:59:59 like this  `$this->_dateTime->date('m/d/Y')."23:59:59"`

Comment: Not working @RakeshVarma

Comment: _dateTime which class is this ?

Comment: use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime;